# Releasing Main View Controller (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

I've searched for this on Apple's site and can only seem to find documentation using Storyboards or Navigation Controllers, neither of which I'm using.  It's an incredibly straightforward question about memory management.

I created a completely blank application.  In my AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function I'm creating an instance of a View Controller which I've built.  My design (which itself could be a problem) is to have a 1:1 relationship between View Controllers and Views.

So the main menu of my application, which is a launching pad for everything is in MenuViewController.h/m.

In .h:

```
MenuViewController *m;
```

In .m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    m = (MenuViewController *)[[MenuViewController alloc] init];
    m.window = self.window;
    [m doStuff]; // handful of functions, not actually called this
    //[m release]; // doesn't make sense to me
    return YES;
}
```

This is where I'm confused.  I want this to exist for basically the entirety of the application life cycle.  But I'm also under the impression that you should (in the scope of the current function) release anything you allocate.  If you need it beyond that, you should retain it elsewhere first.  Is this not true?

My fundamental question is...where should I be releasing this View Controller?  Is there anything else I've said that seems out of whack?

Comment: Why didn't you use automatic reference counting? (Maybe you could release it in `applicationWillTerminate:application` of the AppDelegate)

Comment: You will release it before you move onto the next view. You can also do it in viewDidUnload or dealloc method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initialization is wrong. You don't assign a window to controller, you assign a controller to window:

```
    // window creation code here
    ...
    m = [[MenuViewController alloc] init];
    [window setRootViewController:m]; // window does retain for m
    [m release]; // so we release it here
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES
}
```

Comment: RootViewController to me implies one.  Is it incorrect/poor design to have a view controller for every "screen" in my application?  I currently have one for the Main Menu, the loading screen, a screen for creating users, a screen for managing other data, etc.

Comment: That is exactly how you're supposed to do it. Of course in some cases it can be reasonable to use a view controller subclass more then once, but for screens that are very different in nature and function you usually have a separate view controller subclass.

Comment: @JamesB41 that's why most apps have tabbar controllers or navigation controllers who allow for a few view controllers to be presented or to have a drill-down navigation.

Comment: Ok, but can their only be one RootViewController?  If I'm showing another full screen part of my app, do I then set the new controller as the RootViewController?  What does that do, other than bring it to the front (I assume?)?

Comment: Yes, there can be only one rootviewcontroller. And if you must change it to display another screen - you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Therein lies the rub.  What am I misunderstanding?  I don't want to use a navigation based or tab based application.  I just want different views to be presented at a given time.  I display my initial view which is the one that launches everything and when I want to display another view, I created an instance of that view's view controller and added the subview to the window.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. Generally you should release anything you create in a scope. But in this case you want ownership of the view controller. In this case you need to release the object in the `dealloc` method of your app delegate:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [m release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Alternatively you could define a @`property` for your view controller with retain flag and then do this:

```
MenuViewController *viewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] init];
self.m = viewController;
[viewController release];
```

Btw, you don't need to cast to MenuViewController in either case.

EDIT: I completely missed that you don't add your view controller to your window. Good point @Eimantas.

Comment: I only needed to cast it because I'm calling a method on it from the AppDelegate afterward and it was throwing a warning.

Comment: Did you import the header of your view controller in your app delegate? If your variable (m) is of type MenuViewController (which it is according to your post) and the value you are passing to it is the of the same type, then you don't need to cast. That warning had to have an other reason.